# Add with value not working

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to make a search function in my website but it isn't working

In my code a bit up I typed

```
        if(txtZoeken.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            naam = txtZoeken.Text;
        }

        string Query = "SELECT Naam, Omschrijving,Prijs,Productnummer,CategorieNaam FROM Producten INNER JOIN Categorie ON Producten.Categorie = Categorie.CategorieId WHERE naam LIKE '%@naam%'";
        OleDbCommand SqlQuery = new OleDbCommand(Query, Conn);
        SqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam",naam);
```

If I use it like this

```
        string Query = "SELECT Naam, Omschrijving,Prijs,Productnummer,CategorieNaam FROM Producten INNER JOIN Categorie ON Producten.Categorie = Categorie.CategorieId WHERE naam LIKE '%"+txtZoeken.text+"%'";
        OleDbCommand SqlQuery = new OleDbCommand(Query, Conn);
        SqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam",naam);
```

it is working.

Comment: Describe "not working". Are you getting an exception? Is the output different than what you expect? When you post a question to Stack Overflow, make sure you give all relevant information.

Comment: it doesn't give an error but it also doesn't show anything if i use the second way the program shows the searched items

Comment: in my code a bit up i posted

Comment: if(txtZoeken.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                naam = txtZoeken.Text;
            }

Comment: Then include that information in the question, don't post relevant information in the comments where it's easy to miss. Please update your question with all relevant information.

Comment: Sorry about that didn't think about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, the problem is probably with the quotation marks in the query.

Try this:

```
    if(txtZoeken.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        naam = "%" + txtZoeken.Text + "%";
    }

    string Query = "SELECT Naam, Omschrijving,Prijs,Productnummer,CategorieNaam FROM Producten INNER JOIN Categorie ON Producten.Categorie = Categorie.CategorieId WHERE naam LIKE ?";
    OleDbCommand SqlQuery = new OleDbCommand(Query, Conn);
    SqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam",naam);
```

I removed the quotation marks form the query and put the pattern in the variable.

Answer (score 1):

An excerpt from [OleDbCommand.Paramters documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx).

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

Therefore, change it to this:

```
string Query = "SELECT Naam, Omschrijving, Prijs, Productnummer, CategorieNaam FROM Producten INNER JOIN Categorie ON Producten.Categorie = Categorie.CategorieId WHERE naam LIKE '%?%'";

OleDbCommand SqlQuery = new OleDbCommand(Query, Conn);

SqlQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam",naam);
```